# Android App without launch icons

Tags: android, icons

I start to create small apps android that run in background, but I can not find how to put without launch icon, can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Delete that from your manifest:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: When I removed this line console: [2013-08-03 12:43:27 - icones] Installing icones.apk...
[2013-08-03 12:43:31 - icones] Success!
[2013-08-03 12:43:31 - icones] \icones\bin\icones.apk installed on device
[2013-08-03 12:43:31 - icones] Done!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: When I removed this line console: [2013-08-03 12:43:27 - icones] Installing icones.apk... [2013-08-03 12:43:31 - icones] Success! [2013-08-03 12:43:31 - icones] \icones\bin\icones.apk installed on device [2013-08-03 12:43:31 - icones] Done!